# Редактор brekets выдает ошибку

Tags: javascript, brackets

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Эта строка выведена с помощью Javascript");
</script>
```

1 ошибка jslint:

```
document.write can be a form of eval (document.write("Эта строка выведена с помощью Javascript");)
```

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае, `jslint` указывает на то, что метод `document.write` может иметь код, в котором может использоваться `eval()` метод.
Про минусы метода `eval()` можно прочитать [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/eval#%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-eval).

Comment: Верно, но не совсем. `document.write('<script>...</script>')` - сам аналог eval